# set a time limit on feature then force in-app purchase android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I would like to implement a feature in my application that allows the user to use the app for two weeks, then forces the user to do an in-app purchase, or the app no longer works. Is there a way to do this? Here were a couple of options I thought of (that I don't really like)

- submit an update after two weeks that has in app purchasing as a must (I don't like this option because it seems like a good way to piss off users)
- use a timer, but I don't want to force the app to run in the background for two weeks just to keep an accurate count of the two weeks.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you store the current time (eg. System.currentTimeInMillis()) in Flash (SharedPreference) the first time the application runs?
And trigger the in-app purchase whenever the current time is 14 days after the stored value?

Comment: I just thought of that and was about to send an edit! Thanks. It seems like this will work.

Comment: This will work fine, just be aware that it can be circumvented by the user setting their device time back.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *really* need to change it to in-app purchase exactly after two weeks. You just need to not allow the user to use that feature without in-app purchase after two weeks. So you don't need to necessarily keep an accurate count of the two weeks, just check the time before using the feature (or periodically while running). The only problem with this is the "accurate count of the two weeks" part since the user could presumably change the device clock. I'm guessing you probably already require internet access already, so this can be worked around by just getting the time from a server.